# Convert RS232 Ascii to Modbus TCP using Pymodbus

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, pymodbus

I am trying to convert RS252 Ascii string data from a sensor to Modbus TCP Input/Holding registers using [pymodbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) [Callback Sever](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/common/callback_server.py), the server is the master reporting data when requested to a client logger, and I am not sure what I need to do to get this to work. I am currently able to read the data and log it to a csv file using this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Log data from serial port


import argparse
import serial
import datetime
import time
import os


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-d", "--device", help="device to read from", default="/dev/ttyUSB0")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--speed", help="speed in bps", default=9600, type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

outputFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                 datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ".csv")

with serial.Serial(args.device, args.speed) as ser, open(outputFilePath,'w') as outputFile:
    print("Logging started. Ctrl-C to stop.") 
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.2) 
            x = (ser.read(ser.inWaiting())) 
            data = x.decode('UTF-8')
            if data !="":
                outputFile.write(time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M ") + " " + data  )
                outputFile.flush()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Logging stopped")
```

The string from the sensor comes out of the device as:

```
 0.00 0.0 0.0 346.70 25.14
```

I need to have each piece as its own Modbus register and I am trying to use pymodbus on a Raspberry Pi Zero. The sensor updates 4 times a second and I am able to break the data into parts, I just haven;t gotten to that yet because I am not sure what I need to do in the Callback script, I am not that versed in Python yet I am I am still learning. I do have an understanding of Modbus TCP and have used it before on Arduino systems. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [updating server](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/common/updating_server.py), which you could use to populate the registers . You will have to focus on function `def updating_writer` and do the serial reads, process them and write to registers of your choice. The example is hard to read and understand in first go. I have modified the [example](https://gist.github.com/dhoomakethu/540b15781c62de6d1f7c318c3fc8ae22) to meet your needs. But here are some key concepts which will be handy to understand the code.

[ModbusSlaveContext](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.datastore.html#pymodbus.datastore.context.ModbusSlaveContext)

[BinaryPayloadBuilder](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.html#pymodbus.payload.BinaryPayloadBuilder)

Also note, the example uses asynchronous server based on twisted, If you are new to twisted or have some constraints which will not allow you to use twisted on your target, you can achieve the same with simple threads as well. The design would be roughly like this.

1. Start your updating function in a separate thread
2. Start your TCP server at the end (blocking)

```
# Complete gist here --> https://gist.github.com/dhoomakethu/540b15781c62de6d1f7c318c3fc8ae22
def updating_writer(context, device, baudrate):
    """ A worker process that runs every so often and
    updates live values of the context. It should be noted
    that there is a race condition for the update.
    :param arguments: The input arguments to the call
    """
    log.debug("updating the context")
    log.debug("device - {}, baudrate-{}".format(device, baudrate))
    data = serial_reader(device, baudrate)  # Implement your serial reads, return list of floats.
    if data:
        # We can not directly write float values to registers, Use BinaryPayloadBuilder to convert float to IEEE-754 hex integer
        for d in data:
            builder.add_32bit_float(d)
        registers = builder.to_registers()
        context = context
        register = 3  # Modbus function code (3) read holding registers. Just to uniquely identify what we are reading from /writing in to.
        slave_id = 0x01 # Device Unit address , refer ModbusSlaveContext below
        address = 0x00 # starting offset of register to write (0 --> 40001)
        log.debug("new values: " + str(registers))
        context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, registers)
```

Once the server is running and the values are being updated, you can use a client to read values and parse it back to float.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as Client
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder, Endian
client = Client(<IP-ADDRESS>, port=5020)

# Each 32 bit float is stored in 2 words, so we will read 10 registers 
raw_values = client.read_holding_registers(0, 10, unit=1)
if not registers.isError():
    registers = raw_values.registers
    decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(registers, 
    wordorder=Endian.Big, byteorder=Endian.Big)

    for _ in range(5):
        print(decoder.decode_32bit_float())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will test this out as soon as I can. I have been struggling with this for over a week and this has been the best answer I have gotten yet.

Comment: DEBUG:pymodbus.server.async:Client Connected [IPv4Address(type='TCP', host='192.168.1.102', port=5020)]
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.async:Data Received: 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x6 0x0 0x3 0x9c 0x41 0x0 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.socket_framer:Processing: 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x6 0x0 0x3 0x9c 0x41 0x0 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[3]
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.async:Datastore unable to fulfill request: 'dict' object has no attribute 'validate'
ERROR:pymodbus.pdu:Exception Response(131, 3, SlaveFailure)
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.async:send: 000100000003008304

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1267, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1276, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 902, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  (Part1/2)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 239, in __call__
    d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.f, *self.a, **self.kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "updating_server.py", line 82, in updating_writer
    context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, registers)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'setValues' (part 2/2)

Comment: What version of pymodbus are you working with, this should work on pymodbus==2.2.0rc4

Comment: Python ver. 2.7.13

Comment: Pymodbus ver 2.1.0

Comment: Ok, I have updated the script to be compatible with 2.1.0,  Please give it a try .

Comment: Okay I can now connect and grab data but it doesn;t seem to clear and update the same registers, but adds new ones on the end, basically appending them?

Comment: Since this is basing the builder.to_registers on a 32bit "d" value to have it only right in the first 10 registers would I need to make sure d is <= 10?

Comment: Nope the values  of first 10 registers will be overwritten on every serial read. If you could share the logs of the server and reads it will be helpful to debug further

Comment: Also the binary payload builder is only used to convert raw float values to hex, the actual write to the data block happen with `setValues ` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189960/discussion-between-michael-h-and-sanju).

Comment: I can't add a reasonable sized snippet in the comments.

Comment: added builder.reset() after line 82 and the problem went away. I might be wrong on this but it looks like the builder.add_32bit_float(d) on line 75 appended it buffer so the new values got written in higher registers instead of rewriting the original 10.